# Where foldLeft/foldRight and fold in Option class come from?

Tags: scala

When I try to use an Option variable . I find there are 4 fold methods .

`fold[B](ifEmpty:=>B)(f:Int=>B)`
`fold[A1 >: Int](z : A1)(op : (A1 , A1) => A1)`
`foldLeft[B](z : B)(op : (B , Int) => B)`
`foldRight[B](z : B)(op : (Int , B) => B)`

The first method `fold[B](ifEmpty:=>B)(f:Int=>B)` comes from Option class.
The other 3 methods come from TraversableOnce trait .

So my question is :
1> Why could the variable use the foldLeft/foldRight method from TraversableOnce trait while Option class doesn't extends TraversableOnce  ?
2> Why can't I use fold method but foldLeft/foldRight method from TraversableOnce trait ? Becuase when I use `fold[A1 >: Int](z : A1)(op : (A1 , A1) => A1)`. IDE doesn't compile successfully .

```
    val x = Some(5)
    x.fold(0)( (a) => a)
    x.fold(0)( (a,b) => a + b) //compile failed 

    val y = List(5)
    y.fold(0)( (a,b) => a + b)
```

Comment: which version of scala?

Comment: You can use ```fold``` on ```Option``` and Option extends ```IterableOnce```. See the docs for both https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html#fold[B](ifEmpty:=%3EB)(f:A=%3EB):B

Most IDEs can't handle Scala's type inference properly. Make sure you compile through sbt to see if there is an issue

Comment: @1565986223 : scala-2.11.12

Comment: @sinanspd I did't see Option extends IterableOnce . I just found ```sealed abstract class Option[+A]() extends scala.AnyRef with scala.Product with scala.Serializable```

Comment: That's the difference between Scala versions. In 2.13 `Option` does inherit from IterableOnce, in 2.11 it does not. https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.12/#scala.Option

Comment: @dukyz yeah Option didn't inherit in 2.11 but it did have all 4 fold methods defined on it, so you weren't using the ones from ```TraversableOnce``` but from Option itself https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.12/#scala.Option

Comment: @sinanspd Yes . In 2.11 . foldLeft and foldRight is added by an implicit conversion from Option[A] to Iterable[A] performed by method option2Iterable in scala.Option . But as it is an implicit conversion . Why there is no fold added ? if added , then why can't I use it ?

Comment: the `fold` (which failed to compile) is under `Shadowed Implicit Value Members` (shadowed by the one that compiled) https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.12/index.html#scala.Option@fold[A1%3E:A](z:A1)(op:(A1,A1)=%3EA1):A1 so yeah you can't use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Option` has an implicit conversion to `Iterable[T]` [Option$](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.12/#scala.Option$)
2. the `fold` method is defined by `Option` itself and it is available due to the implicit conversion to `Iterable[T]`, but because the method is directly defined on the class itself, implicit conversion is not attempted. You can force it:

```
val o: Option[Int] = Some(5)
(o: Iterable[Int]).fold(0)((a, b) => a + b)
```